# Webpack won't compile SASS if a hexadecimal color is passed

Tags: webpack, sass

I'm trying to implement Webpack in an existing project which contain SASS.

So here is my `webpack.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  entry: "./entry.js",
  output: {
      path: __dirname,
      filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['env']
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          { loader: "style-loader" },
          { loader: "css-loader" },
          { loader: "sass-loader" }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx'],
  },
};
```

But, when I run `webpack`, I have this error

```
ERROR in ./style.scss
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '#' (1:8)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| $color: #bebebe;
|
| body {
 @ ./entry.js 3:13-36
```

And I have no idea why. Every solutions I found was because `css-loader` was missing. But, not in my case.

Comment: you are configuring webpack to load files ending with .css through the Sass loader, but not files ending with.scss, that's why your attempt to load an scss file fails, because it is _not_ loaded through the sass loader

Comment: While @PatrickHund points out the issue, would like to add that webpack can still process a `css` file that has `scss` code. The loaders will take care of processing irrespective of the file extension. However, this is true in this case but it may not be so in case of other loaders i.e. they can still fail if the extension is wrong. More over there is no sane reason for having wrong file extension.